# How do I delete a signature in Foxit Reader?

Tags: pdf, foxit-reader

I am using Foxit Reader version 7.1.5.425 and “Manage Signatures” only allows me to *add* a signature, not delete a signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  The manual says

> To manage the signature, do the following: Choose PROTECT tab >
>   Protect > PDF Sign > Manage Signature. In the Manage Signature dialog
>   box, click Create to create a signature. Select a signature you
>   created, click Edit and you can change your signature. You can preview
>   the signature after you edit it. To delete a signature, select the
>   signature and click Delete.

I couldn't figure out how to select because the various signatures I had created weren't in a dropdown list, or separated by anything.  Nevertheless, it turns out they *are* selectable:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I thought it should be like, but my copy of Foxit Reader didn't have "Manage Signatures" in *Protect* > *PDF Sign*. [Adolfo's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1286475/776028) worked for me.

Comment: @3D1T0R - What version were you using?  Was it an older version?

Comment: I had been on an older version previously, but since this option wasn't available to me, I ran the built in updater (I'm now on Version:  9.2.0.9297) and it still isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows first find the file with the signature you want to delete. For this you need to open a command prompt (black screen):

```
dir %SystemDrive%\ /b /s | find /i "InstaSign" | find /i "UserSign"
```

Then open that directory and delete the signature file. Signatures are PDF documents that you can open with Foxit itself. Just delete what you want.

If you want to search only within your account use this version:

```
dir %HOMEPATH%\ /b /s | find /i "InstaSign" | find /i "UserSign"
```

Comment: They're saved in `%APPDATA%\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\InstaSign\UserSign`.

Answer (score 1):

Old post, nevertheless had the same problem today (v. 9.6.0.25114) and could not find an answer online. In fact the Manage Signatures command is hidden in the Signature List sub menu. Easiest way to get there, Type "Manage Signatures" (or just "Manage" and it will show you a drop down list)in the search menu (next to the light bulb, in the "Tell me what you want to do" field). Then go to Signatures List, Manage Signatures, then select and delete the signature you want to get rid of. Commands work if you have opened an existing pdf or new pdf, not when you just start the programme in the welcome page. Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Using Foxit reader Version 9.6.0.25114
Here is the easiest solution that I found.

Go to the "Tell me what you want to do..." search box and type in Signature List.
Then open the menu and chose Manage Signatures.
The Manage Signature dialog box will open and you can select and delete the signatures you no longer want to keep.

Comment: Definitively usable. It opens up quick access to a lot of options, a sort of omnibar. I am long time user of Foxit, but always overlooked this. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File/Preferences/Signature

Answer (score 0):

Menu Fill&Sign, double click the dash+arrow button on the right hand side. Select manage signatures then delete the ones you don't need anymore.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hMz9.png)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, for advanced editing you need [FoxitPhantomPDF.](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-editor/)

Comment: I'm just trying to manage my collection of signatures, not edit the document.

Answer (score -2):

I have phantom standard and had a signature I no longer have the password for. It took me forever to find the "manage signature" spot, but to delete it I still needed the password.
I found the file in appdata>roaming>foxit software>foxit PhantomPDF>Instasign>UserSign. From here I could delete it without a password. 
Of course, this is windows based directions, but I imagine Mac has a similar user file that probably very very hidden because they don't trust their users at all. Maybe something to do with dragging the harddrive to the trash.

Comment: So, do you have an answer to the question of how to delete a signature in Foxit Reader?  If so, please explain it.